# Storyboard - Presenting Modal View Controller over Storyboard's 1st view

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Using storyboard, I created a tab-bar app with 5 tabs, each containing a UINavigation controller.
When a Push Notification arrives, the AppDelegate handles it by presenting a UIAlertView which lets the user choose to either view the notification, or cancel it.
If they choose to view it, I want to present a Modal View Controller with whatever the new updated content is (basically just some simple text.)
But how can I present a modal view-controller over a storyboard generated view? The storyboard doesn't load any NIB file, so how I can push another NIB onto a non-existing NIB? Can this even be done?
I tried using segues - but I don't have any segued views in my app to begin with, and when I tried to create one and `performSegueWithIdentifier` - crash! 
Frankly, at this point I'd be happy to navigate to one of my existing views already sitting inside one of my Navigation Controllers - and do away with the whole Modal thing - but again, how do I `push` or `present` anything over nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I think creating a new view controller and then present it modally. I may be wrong--I never used Nibs before.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewNib" owner:self options:nil];
viewController.view = self.myViewFromNib;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

And in you .h; don't forget to synethize and all that.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myViewFromNib;
```

I'm not sure if it works with NIBs, but I could present a new VC from the storyboard this way.